# Accessing resources in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android

I have class that works fine in original book [sample](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid2ndEdition/tree/master/chapter12/BitsandPizzas) project:

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new TopFragment();
            case 1:
                return new PizzaFragment();
            case 2:
                return new PastaFragment();
            case 3:
                return new StoresFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.home_tab);
            case 1:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.pizza_tab);
            case 2:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.pasta_tab);
            case 3:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.store_tab);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Android Studio complains regarding `getResources` in the same class in my newly created project.

```
error: cannot find symbol method getResources()
```

I have noticed that in working project base class FragmentPagerAdapter refers to 
som `26.0.0-alpha1` library when not compiling project refers to `28.0.0` library.

Might library difference create such problem?  How to make my new project work?

Comment: Also, the method doesn't exist in [the class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter) or [the superclass](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html). You need a Context

Comment: try `getActivity().getResources().getText(R.string.pasta_tab);`

Comment: But I would like to understand why the same class works in original project while files in created by me

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor

```
private Context context;
 SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context) {
 this.context = context;
 }
```

So

```
context.getResources();
```

else

```
getActivity().getResources();
```

Answer (score 0):

`getResources()` only exist inside a class that extends the `Context` base class, your class extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` which is an adapter and not a derived class of `Context`.

To fix that, you either include this adapter inside an `Activity` or a `Fragment`, or extend the Application class and use it to call `getResources()` as explained [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class)

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor to

```
private Context context;
public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, 
FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}
```

after that, go to method getPageTitle and replace getResources() with context.getResources()

e.g.:
      context.getResources().getText(R.string.home_tab);